# Method name "Media_Content_Taxonomy::mctf_register_media_content_taxonomy" is not in camel caps format

Tags: wordpress, phpcodesniffer

I am using `PHPCS` for the first time with `standard=WordPress`. While sniffing a class file I get the following error:

```
Method name "Media_Content_Taxonomy::mctf_register_media_content_taxonomy" is not in camel caps format.
```

I Googled but could not find an exact work around for this.

I tried by changing the method name to (may be wild guesses!)

```
Mctf_Register_Media_Content_Taxonomy
```

and

```
MctfRegisterMediaContentTaxonomy
```

but could not get rid of the error. I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress Coding Standards use a [naming convention](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#naming-conventions) of class names with underscores, so you appear to be running PHP_CodeSniffer without using the `WordPress` standard.

Try running `phpcs -i` to check it (and the sub-standards) is installed.